# can we validate value of guestInfo properties set in ovf file

Tags: vsphere, esxi

I have set guestInfo properties in ovf file in ProductSection and i am able to read those properties inside VM, but i want to validate those properties when user tries to set values from UI during deployment of ova/ovf

eg.

```
        <Property ovf:key="guestinfo.ipv4.ipaddr" ovf:type="string"  ovf:userConfigurable="true"ovf:value="10.243.16.53">
                <Label>IPv4 IPAddress</Label>
                <Description>IP address for IPv4.(required only when IPv4 protocol is static, else can keep it blank)</Description>
  </Property>
```

i want to validate user input(ip address) to see if its valid ipv4 or not and indicate user about it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the only way you can detect if someone has added extraConfig is through the vCenter events. How you go about indicating that to the user is up to you.

A potential solution might be to use [GOVC to detect an extraConfig event](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/blob/master/govc/USAGE.md#events), or another vSphere CLI/SDK:

```
govc events -f | grep 'extraConfig'
```

The above command will return something like this when someone alters the extraConfig:

```
config.extraConfig("guestinfo.test"): (key = "guestinfo.test", value = "I am some extraConfig");
```

You could then parse this and if it is invalid ipv4, trigger an alarm on the object, or whatever you deem to be appropriate.

A more rigorous solution would be to produce a [vSphere local plugin](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/f7ffd9f7-9f92-444c-9529-40913be95870/e6f15e3b-361a-4dac-83e8-d0a4e8b83d0b/vsphere-client-sdk-671-local-programming-guide.pdf) to allow your users to add extraConfig in a manner that you can control and validate.

Hope this helps!